# i want to make call on an emergency number by pressing the button in my mobile app with help of ACTION_CALL but i didn't. why?

Tags: java, android

i want to make call on an emergency number by pressing the button in my mobile app with help of ACTION_CALL but i didn't. why?

I implemented CALL_PHONE permission in my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

and this is my java code to call.

```
public void makeCall(View v){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "making call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:108"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "making call is not possible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        }
    }
```

this code takes me onto default dialer of mobile.

How can i call on an emergency number directly by my app without reaching on default dialer?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+123));//change the number

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},12);
    }else{
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

Comment: what does the log say

Comment: it says- java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB and after this on onClick of button it takes me onto default dialer of mobile phone.

Comment: hi.. i have updated my answer check with it... it works fine with me

Comment: this makes an emergency number, as invalid number.

Comment: if 108 is an emergency number in your locality then only it would make a call.

Comment: yes it is an emergency number but it wouldn't call on it.

Comment: Just try with another phone number... check if it is works with normal phone number